# Archlinux pocketsphinx

Tags: ros, archlinux, pocketsphinx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to get pocketsphinx running on archlinux: http://wiki.ros.org/pocketsphinx.

I have the file libgstpocketsphinx.so in /usr/lib/gstreamer-0.10 (I also have one in /usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0 as a result of a failed attempt to make this work). However, I keep getting the error glib.GError: no element "vader". From what I read so far, for ubuntu users this was because they were missing the mentioned .so file. However, I do have this file and it is in a place where it should be easily to find. Any idea on how I can solve this? Thanks in advance.

Wilson

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214228/archlinux-pocketsphinx/) by [HououinKyouma](https://answers.ros.org/users/22280/hououinkyouma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2015-07-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2015-07-22**:
If gst-inspect-0.10 does not show the vader element then this is a gstreamer problem which should be asked to the gstreamer people.

**Comment by [HououinKyouma](https://answers.ros.org/users/22280/hououinkyouma/) on 2015-07-23**:
Thanks for your reply, I will check that out, thanks

**Comment by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) on 2017-08-05**:
any progress? kinetic, using indigo source code, same problem here. gstreamer0.10-gconf installed. all gstreamer components installed.

**Comment by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) on 2017-08-05**:
ubuntu 16.04

**Comment by [HououinKyouma](https://answers.ros.org/users/22280/hououinkyouma/) on 2017-09-29**:
Sorry for the late response, but unfortunately I was never able to really solve this. I had this problem on Archlinux, back then Ubuntu didn't have this problem. In the end I just installed Ubuntu and installed everything with ap-get, which worked for me. Not sure what the real fix would be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately the pocketsphinx package which is mentioned in the ROS wiki was developed back in 2011. It is no longer recommended to use GStreamer with pocketsphinx.
You should instead use this package:
https://github.com/cmusphinx/ros-pocketsphinx
It has most of the up-to-date features of pocketsphinx, and a great wiki can be found in the parent repository:
https://github.com/Pankaj-Baranwal/cmu-pocketsphinx/wiki
It will walk you through the installation and demonstration of the basic working of the package.
This will help you get the same functionalities as provided by the 2011 package by MikeFerguson and set it up on any linux system with ease!

---

Originally posted by [PankajBaranwal](https://answers.ros.org/users/29651/pankajbaranwal/) with karma: 96 on 2017-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0